# What determines my actual screen width for a MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I found the data sheet [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP813?locale=en_US) which states these numbers ...

> 13.3-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit display with IPS technology; 2560-by-1600 native resolution at 227 pixels per inch with support for
> millions of colors
>
> Supported scaled resolutions:  1680 by 1050 1440 by 900 1024 by 640

When I actually measure the width I get 1440 pixels.

I do this by using a grid image that is 100px wide as a background for my website in Google Chrome.

Just curious to how I have 2560 Native and how this is scaled to 1440.

1440 just happens to be

1024 + 256 + 128 + 32

Comment: Using the browser in such a way could yield incorrect results. Please verify using a native tool, for example [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) or any other resolution switcher app.

Comment: And of, course, check your setting in System Preferences > Display , whether it's set to a scaled mode.

Comment: Also, please make sure your post actually includes a question :-)